# Compiling with ocamlbuild and camlp5

Tags: preprocessor, flags, ocamlbuild, camlp4

I am trying to make a project I am working on compile with ocamlbuild, in order to avoid the use of a regular Makefile, which I find to be slightly more complicated.

Specifically, I have a syntax extension file (extend.ml), which I need to be compiled first. In a regular Makefile there would be a rule:

```
extend.cmo: extend.ml
    $(OCAMLC) -pp "camlp5o pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo" -I +camlp5 -c $<
```

and then, for calculating the dependencies there would be a rule like this:

```
depend: $(MLFILES) extend.cmo
    $(OCAMLDEP) -pp "camlp5o ./extend.cmo"
```

Of course, the creation of any object file would require a similar rule to the one above.

---

**My question is**, how can I integrate these rules/requirements to **one ocamlbuild command** (if possible)?

I have tried to compile the extend.ml file first, and then use the following command:

```
ocamlbuild -pp "camlp5o ./extend.cmo" -I +camlp5 -use-menhir -no-hygiene Main.byte
```

but I don't think it's optimal in any way.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the use of ocamlbuild as a compilation tool, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a tarball with your code (or a simplified version thereof) to allow us to experiment to check that proposed solutions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define two new tags, `compile_extend` and `use_extend`, that specify the expected options. In your myocamlbuild.ml file:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin

let my_flags () =
  flag ["ocaml"; "pp"; "compile_extend"]
    (S [A"camlp5o"; A "pa_extend.cmo"; A "q_MLast.cmo"]);
  flag ["ocaml"; "pp"; "use_extend"]
    (S [A"camlp5o"; A "extend.cmo"]);
  (* files with the use_extend flag must depend on extend.cmo *)      
  dep  ["ocaml"; "use_extend"] ["extend.cmo"];
   ()

let () =
  dispatch (function
    | After_rules ->
      my_flags (); 
    | _ -> ())
```

Then you would have a tags file with:

```
"extend.cmo": compile_extend
<Main.*>: use_extend
```

That  said, this is all bling guessing, I have not tested this setup. Could you provide a tarball with an example `extend.ml` file and `Main.ml` allowing to reproduce your situation?

Comment: Man, I wish this answer had came up sooner, it would have saved me a lot of trouble. Anyway, I came up with a similar solution myself about 1.5 month ago, but completely forgot to post a reply. Turned out, I needed an ocamlbuild plugin just like the one you are proposing. Thank you very much for your time. I am posting below links to my files, if you would like to see for yourself what did the trick.

myocamlbuild.ml: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dd66zl7zy52jsp/myocamlbuild.ml?dl=0
_tags file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0a5taua9rj9h5e/_tags?dl=0